# arrange values in a order in a pandas df

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

i have a table in pandasas df:

```
p_id_x    p_id_y    count
  a         b         2
  b         c         4
  a         c         8
  d         a         1 
  x         a         6
  m         b         3
  c         z         7
```

i wam tring to write a function

```
def function_combination(p_id):
    df[['p_id_x', 'p_id_y']] = df[['p_id_x', 'p_id_y']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
    df.groupby(['p_id_x', 'p_id_y'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
```

(the function is not completed and has errors.)
and i got the result by seperately running the code inside the function.

```
df['p_id_x','p_id_y']

p_id_x  p_id_y
  a         b
  b         c
  a         c
  a         d
  a         x
  b         m
  c         z
```

but what i want my output to look like is:

```
p_id_x    p_id_y
  a         b
  a         c
  a         d
  a         x         
  b         c
  b         m
  c         z
```

i'e all the combinations for a first, followed by b, and followed by c.

this is only a part of my rows. i've 20+ such rows.
is there a way to do this, so that i can have both my codes inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `p_id_x`:

```
df[['p_id_x', 'p_id_y']] = df[['p_id_x', 'p_id_y']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df = df.groupby(['p_id_x', 'p_id_y'], as_index=False)['count'].sum().sort_values('p_id_x')

print (df)
  p_id_x p_id_y  count
0      a      b      2
1      a      c      8
2      a      d      1
3      a      x      6
4      b      c      4
5      b      m      3
6      c      z      7

print (df[['p_id_x','p_id_y']])
  p_id_x p_id_y
0      a      b
1      a      c
2      a      d
3      a      x
4      b      c
5      b      m
6      c      z
```

EDIT by comment - use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.p_id_x == 'a') & (df['count'] > 3)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  p_id_x p_id_y  count
1      a      c      8
3      a      x      6
```

Or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (df.query("p_id_x == 'a' and count > 3"))
  p_id_x p_id_y  count
1      a      c      8
3      a      x      6
```

Comment: is there a way i can get count of each value in my p_id_x?
i wan to give a if condition inside my function i.e say `if count of a > 3 then do something`

Comment: yes, actually i just realised i have done a huge mistake at my start.
say if i have combinations (a-c),and (c-a) ` .apply(sorted)` will comvert (c-a) to (a-c) thus my combinations of c will be lost. which is hampering my solution. i'll look to solve it by other way. and then use your solution

Comment: is there a way to use .apply(sorted) and also keep my orignal row (c-a) let it increase the length of my rows.?

Comment: Yes, if use `a-c` is same as `c-a`, it more complicated.

Comment: Maybe try assign output to new columns like `df[['p_id_x1', 'p_id_y1']] = df[['p_id_x', 'p_id_y']].apply(sorted, axis=1)`

Comment: But I a mnot sure if understand. The best is create new question with desired output.

Comment: @ i resolved my issue, but `df.query("p_id_x == 'a' and count > 3"))`
 i don't want to do it only for 'a' , i want to find every such instance in p_id_x where count >3

Comment: Do you want `df.query("count > 3")` ?

Comment: i actually didn't wanted the `count` colum >10 but no. of times `a,b,c...` occurs in df.
i did it with `df[p_id_x].value_counts > 10 ` but i got a bool, how to get the true values in df

Comment: It seems you need `df = df.groupby('p_id_x').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 10)`

Comment: see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128925/discussion-between-jezrael-and-s-ringne).

Comment: Sorry, I yesterday have no time to write anser to another your question. Now I try explain it and post it. Please check it and dont forget accept this and another answer. Thank you very much.